# Render text as html with angularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html-rendering

How do I make the string to be rendered as HTML?  When doing something like:

```
<div>
  {{ text }}
</div>
```

The output is just displayed at text meaning " ab "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expression:

```
var pattern = new RegExp(keywords.join('|'), "g");
var result = text.match(pattern);
```

Rending a string as HTML:

```
<div ng-bind-html="text"></div>
```

P.S: Since these are two different questions, next time you should post them separately.

Comment: Right. I have split it to two q. Thanks

Comment: FYI - To use ng-bind-html, you need to include ngSanitize and use $sce.trustAsHtml